# is there any configuration or setup for ftp(file transfer protocol) SPEED on windows server 2008 (r2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, performance

i am using windows server 2008 (r2)  and CuteFTP Pro 8.3.4 for transfer files to my server.

on windows server i have iis,dns,ftp,websitepanel...

my internet speed is 1mbps and server speed is 5 mbps!

but when i want upload files on server, we have only 20kbps speed!

is there any configuration or setup for ftp(file transfer protocol) SPEED on windows server 2008 (r2)?

or is there any config about cuteftp for solving this issue?

`I HAVAE REMOTE ACCESS TO MY SERVER`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your **upload** speed. I'm assuming this isn't a leased line, so it's almost certainly different to your **download** (I.e., quoted) speed.

In short, I'm almost certain that this is

a) Not an issue with your server

b) Not a fault

Also, I'm not understanding what the difference between "server speed" and "internet speed" is. Can you be cleared on your infrastructure?

Finally, can you be clearer whether you're talking about Kilo*bits* or Kilo*bytes* and Mega*bits* or Mega*bytes*. A 20 Kilobyte per second upload is 160Kilobits, which is probably average for a 1Mb domestic broadband connections.